# How to use a variable from module export

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the server file, I export the variable. How can I use it in another js file? Now in the browser in the console I have an error - require is not defined

```js
// server.js

const firestore = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { firestore };

// script.js

const firestore = require("../../server");

const getAllUsers = () => {
  db.listCollections()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((snaps) => {
        console.log(snaps); // LIST OF ALL COLLECTIONS
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};

getAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not support CommonJS modules.

You can either:

- Convert the module to an ECMAScript module using [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and then load the module that is the entry point to your program with [`<script type="module" src="..."></script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type).
- Bundle the modules together with a tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).